# Facebook menu appearing in canvas page frame on feed dialog call

Tags: php, html, facebook

I'm having a problem implementing the feed dialog function of Facebook within my canvas page.

The following code runs after the form is successfully submitted to the MySQL database.

```
header("Location: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=************&
link=".$applink."&
picture=".$apppicture."&
name=".$appname."&
caption=".$appcaption."&
description=".$appdescription."&
redirect_uri=".$redirecturi);
```

It loads the following:

[image: Screen shot of problem]

Ideally I need the header to redirect the location to the _parent frame. I've tried implementing this using Javascript, and a secondary header specifying target preceding the location header - but neither of these methods worked.

I just need some way of either:

1) Not showing the top bar.
2) Hiding it using a CSS hack

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the JavaScript method works – if I doesn’t for you, then you simply did it **wrong**.

Output something like the following in answer to the form submit, and **no** HTTP location header with it:

```
<script>
  window.top.location.href = '…the URL you want the user “redirected” to …';
</script>
```

Surround it by a basic HTML document structure, if you like – but put nothing else in there, like actual data the user is supposed to read.

> I've tried implementing this using [...] a secondary header specifying target preceding the location header - but neither of these methods worked.

There is no “target” for HTTP location headers. You can’t get stuff working by just inventing your own imaginary syntax …

Comment: _“if I doesn’t for you, then you simply did it wrong.”_ Please show us _exactly_ what you did and where.